# React context not update list when edited

Tags: reactjs, list, render

I'm trying to create a simple crud that uses an array to create a list, but the list doesn't update, when I try to remove an element the last one is removed, but when I type in the search bar it updates and returns to normal

Main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ItemsProvider>
      <App />
    </ItemsProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

App.tsx

```
import './App.css'
import { ItemsContext } from './context/Items';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";
import { IoIosAddCircle } from "react-icons/io";
import Card from "./components/Card";

function App() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("")
    const [addInput, setAddInput] = useState<string>("")
    const context = useContext(ItemsContext)
    const items = context?.items

    const addItems = () => {
        if(items) context?.addItem(addInput)
        setAddInput("")
    }

  return (
    <main>
        <nav>
          <input 
            id='searchInput'
            type="text"
            value={search}
            onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          />
          <FaSearch className="inputButton" />
        </nav>  
        <section id='cardBox'>
          {context && context?.items?.map((name: string,index: number) => {
            // if (name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || search == ""){
              return <Card key={index} name={name}/>
            // } 
          }
          )}
        </section>
        <div id='inputFooter'>
          <input 
            id='addInput'
            type="text"
            value={addInput}
            onChange={e => setAddInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <IoIosAddCircle className="inputButton" onClick={() => addItems()}/>
        </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Items.tsx

```
    import { createContext, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

    interface ProviderType{
        items?: string[],
        addItem: (name:string) => void
        removeItem: (name:string) => void
        editItem: (prevName:string,name:string) => void
    }

    interface ChildrenType{
        children: ReactNode
    }

    export const ItemsContext = createContext<ProviderType | undefined>(undefined)

    export const ItemsProvider = ({ children }: ChildrenType) => {
        const [items,setItems] = useState<string[]>(["Henrique","Iris"])

        const addItem = (name: string) => {
            if (items) setItems([...items,name])
        }

        const removeItem = (name: string) => {
            const newArray = items.filter(item => item != name)
            setItems(newArray)
        }

        const editItem = (name: string,prevName: string) => {
            const newArray = items?.map(item => item = item == prevName ? name:prevName)
            setItems(newArray)
        }

        return(
            <ItemsContext.Provider value={{items,addItem,removeItem,editItem}}>
                {children}
            </ItemsContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Card.tsx

```
    import { FaEdit, FaTrash, FaCheck } from "react-icons/fa";
    import { useContext, useState } from "react";
    import { ItemsContext } from "../context/Items";

    interface Props{
        name: string
    }

    function Card(props: Props) {
        const [toogleEdit, setToogleEdit] = useState<boolean>(false)
        const [name,setName] = useState<string>(props.name)
        const [editInput, setEditInput] = useState<string>(name)
        const context = useContext(ItemsContext)

        const changeEdit = () => {
            if(!toogleEdit){
                setToogleEdit(true)
                setEditInput(name)
            }else{
                setToogleEdit(false)
                context?.editItem(name,editInput)
                setName(editInput)
            }
        }

        return ( 
            <div className="card">
                {!toogleEdit && name}
                {toogleEdit && <input 
                    type='text'
                    value={editInput}
                    onChange={e => setEditInput(e.target.value)}
                />}
                <section className="cardButton">
                    {!toogleEdit && <FaEdit onClick={() => changeEdit()}/>}
                    {toogleEdit && <FaCheck onClick={() => changeEdit()}/>}
                    <FaTrash onClick={() => context?.removeItem(name)}/>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default Card;
```

As seen, I already tried using spread operator to avoid the problem of pushing just a new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue is you are using an index as a key value for the Card component. When you delete any element the index value shifts and react assumes the last element was removed, even though the last element is still in the items list. That's why you see it when you search for a value, it was still in the items array but react hides the last Card component.

If every element that is added to the list is guaranteed to be unique, you can use the name as a key:

```
<section id='cardBox'>
      {context && context?.items?.map((name: string,index: number) => {
        if (name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || search == ""){
          return <Card key={name} name={name}/>
        } 
      }
      )}
    </section>
```

But if that's not the case you can use crypto.randomUUID(), which is a built-in method that is found in all modern browsers and runtimes. Here's an example:

```
<section id='cardBox'>
      {context && context?.items?.map((name: string,index: number) => {
        if (name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || search == ""){
          const key=crypto.randomUUID()
          return <Card key={key} name={name}/>
        } 
      }
      )}
    </section>
```

Hope this was helpful